# WordPress quick access link for protected page

Tags: wordpress, password-protection

I'm trying to create quick access link for protected page. For example if the person went to http://example.com/post/?password=PASSWORD they would be straight in without being asked for the password.

So far I've added filter for the 'the_content' which checks if the post is protected, and it compares the value from url with post password.

This part works fine, but how do I return the content after that? Is there any way I can simulate the password form submission, or get content somehow?

```
function render_content_or_not_to_render( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( post_password_required() ) {
        if ( $_GET['password'] == $post->post_password ) {
            return $content; // this way it just returns the password form
        } else {
            return get_the_password_form();
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'render_content_or_not_to_render' );
```

Comment: This screams major security flaws, especially when that password gets cached on all of the search engines as part of the URL. You'd have to be able to still pass the username and password of the user in the URL and parse those in to a request to Wordpress to allow the access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added filter for the 'post_password_required' gets the job done. Not sure about security, please consider this as rookie solution.

```
function modof_post_password_required( $post = null ){
    global $post;
    if ( $_GET['password'] == $post->post_password ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }   
}
add_filter( 'post_password_required', 'modof_post_password_required', 0 );
```